# Ubuntu - xampp - could not import database to mysql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, xampp, virtualbox

I have a project which needs to be run on PHP 5.5. I created a virtual machine with Ubuntu. I have windows 10 on my machine. I could not found version of lamp supporting PHP 5.5, so I installed Xampp. It works and also phpmyadmin works. But when I try to import database from command line, it says - "The program 'mysql' can be found in the following packages......". It asks to install the package. 
The client wants to stick to the current PHP version, until we are up and live with latest versions of PHP.

Do I need to install mysql package separately? Is it possible to use it with Xampp ?

Or can I connect to the database on host (windows 10) ?

Comment: xampp should have it bundled - but it may be the case that ubuntu had mysql preinstalled, so xampp + native are clashing and causing issues, see if you can track down another instance of mysql on the vb

Comment: yes, I had installed one previously, but I had removed it. How can I check if it still exists.

Comment: do `cd /` and run `sudo find .- name "*mysql*"` and see what gets returned

Comment: yes, there few folders with name mysql*

Comment: all under different places? This might be the cause, maybe try finding something along that helps fully uninstall mysql from your machine, then retry with xampp and see what happens :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to remove the mysql related files and folders, but due to file permissions, I could not remove all. With less time in hand, I tried to connect to the host database (xampp installed on windows 10), and it worked.
Here is what I did -

1. Run ipconfig (My host is windows 10).
2. Note the IPv4 address, under "Ethernet adapter Ethernet:".
3. Run following queries on host database (xampp installed on windows 10) -

   CREATE USER 'yourusername'@'IPv4 address:port' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword';

   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'yourusername'@'IPv4 address:port' WITH GRANT OPTION;

   CREATE USER 'yourusername'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'yourusername'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

I used port 3306.

While connecting, I used the IPv4 address:port as host, username = yourusername and password=password.

I hope this helps somebody.